# while loop not executing please assist

Tags: c++

Beginner coder here. I can't seem to figure out why my `while` loop won't execute the code inside:

```cpp
// Rates based on weight
const double ZERO_TO_TEN_POUNDS = 0.75;
const double TEN_TO_FIFTEEN_POUNDS = 0.85;
const double FIFTEEN_TO_TWENTY_POUNDS = 0.95;
const double MAX_POUNDS = 20.0;

// Rates based on distance
const double ZERO_TO_FIFTY_MILES = 0.07;
const double FIFTY_TO_ONEHUNDRED_MILES = 0.06;
const double ONEHUNDRED_TO_TWOHUNDRED_MILES = 0.05;
const double TWOHUNDRED_TO_FIVEHUNDRED_MILES = 0.04;
const double MAX_DISTANCE = 500.0;

double weight,
        distance,
        weightCharges = 0.0,
        distanceCharges = 0.0,
        total;

// Display the menu and get the user's choice
cout << "Welcome to Marie's Shipping Company!\n\n";
cout << "Please enter the weight in pounds of your package: ";
cin >> weight;
cout << "Please enter the distance in miles to be shipped: ";
cin >> distance;

// Set weight charges based on user input
while (weight < MAX_POUNDS)
{
    if (weight <= 10)
        weightCharges = weight * ZERO_TO_TEN_POUNDS;
    else if (weight <= 15)
        weightCharges = weight * TEN_TO_FIFTEEN_POUNDS;
    else if (weight <= 20)
        weightCharges = weight * FIFTEEN_TO_TWENTY_POUNDS;
    else
        cout << "Sorry. Packages over 20 pounds are not allowed\n.";
}

// Set distance charges based on user input
while (distance < MAX_DISTANCE)
{
    if (distance <= 50)
        distanceCharges = distance * ZERO_TO_FIFTY_MILES;
    else if (distance <= 100)
        distanceCharges = distance * FIFTY_TO_ONEHUNDRED_MILES;
    else if (distance <= 200)
        distanceCharges = distance * ONEHUNDRED_TO_TWOHUNDRED_MILES;
    else if (distance <= 500)
        distanceCharges = distance * TWOHUNDRED_TO_FIVEHUNDRED_MILES;
    else
        cout << "Sorry. Packages are not allowed to be shipped over 500 miles.\n";
}

// Calculate and display the total charges
total = weightCharges + distanceCharges;
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
cout << "Your total charge is: $" << total << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What value are you entering as input for `weight`?  Also, since the `while` is entered only if `weight` is less than 20, the `"Sorry. Packages over 20 pounds are not allowed\n."` message will never be reached.  Did you mean to put `cin >> weight;` *inside* the loop, perhaps?

Comment: Why is this a loop? It either doesn't loop at all or infinitely loops, depending on `weight`. There is no other possibility given this code.

Comment: I entered 2.5 for my weight.

Comment: I used the loop for input validation.

Comment: @mphil OK, well `2.5` is less than `20.0`, so your `while` loop MUST be getting entered, given the way you have shown the code. [Proof](https://ideone.com/51ZENy) Are you saying it doesn't? That would imply that `weight` is not receiving `2.5`, did you try verifying that yet?  Is this your complete program? It is not a [mcve].

Comment: I'm assuming it doesn't because I also have a similar while loop for distance charges. From the user input, it's supposed to calculate the total charges (weight + distance) and display it after the loops execute. However, after entering values that make the while loop true, the total calculation doesn't execute or display. Thank you so much for your help as well.

Answer (score 0):

here you need selection statement, not a iteration statement.

So, replace while loop with if statement like this:

`while (weight < MAX_POUNDS)`
to
`if (weight < MAX_POUNDS)`

`while (distance < MAX_DISTANCE)`
to
`if (distance < MAX_DISTANCE)`

And if you want to put whole program in loop, and asking user to **exit** or not then you can add while loop like this :

```
    double weight,
    distance,
    weightCharges = 0.0,
    distanceCharges = 0.0,
    total;
    char end = 'n';

     // Display the menu and get the user's choice
     cout << "Welcome to Marie's Shipping Company!\n\n";
     cout << "Please enter the weight in pounds of your package: ";
     cin >> weight;
     cout << "Please enter the distance in miles to be shipped: ";
     cin >> distance;

     while (end == 'n')
     {

    // Set weight charges based on user input
    if (weight < MAX_POUNDS)
    {
     if (weight <= 10)
     weightCharges = weight * ZERO_TO_TEN_POUNDS;
     else if (weight <= 15)
     weightCharges = weight * TEN_TO_FIFTEEN_POUNDS;
     else if (weight <= 20)
     weightCharges = weight * FIFTEEN_TO_TWENTY_POUNDS;
     else
     cout << "Sorry. Packages over 20 pounds are not allowed\n.";
     }

    // Set distance charges based on user input
    if (distance < MAX_DISTANCE)
    {
    if (distance <= 50)
       distanceCharges = distance * ZERO_TO_FIFTY_MILES;
    else if (distance <= 100)
       distanceCharges = distance * FIFTY_TO_ONEHUNDRED_MILES;
    else if (distance <= 200)
       distanceCharges = distance * ONEHUNDRED_TO_TWOHUNDRED_MILES;
    else if (distance <= 500)
       distanceCharges = distance * TWOHUNDRED_TO_FIVEHUNDRED_MILES;
    else
       cout << "Sorry. Packages are not allowed to be shipped over 500      miles.\n";
    }

   // Calculate and display the total charges
   total = weightCharges + distanceCharges;
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
   cout << "Your total charge is: $" << total << endl;
   
   cout << "do you want to exit ? (y or n)" << endl;
   cin >> end;
   }
   return 0;
   }
```